discord.py - how to use a slash command as a reply to a message?
I wanted to create a function to translate messages that the user responds to with /translate, but I wanted the bot's response to be in ephemeral mode, this is only possible with slash commanda
I wanted slash commands to accept responses to other messages or send ephemera messages with @commands.command()

Does this answer your question? How would I send an ephemeral message in discord.py?

You can't reply to messages if you're also using a slash command. For your desired outcome, use Context Menus.

Here's an example for Pearoo's answer:
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all() #Change however you want
bot = commands.Bot(intents=intents,command_prefix="!!")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged in as {bot.user.name}")
    try:
        synced = await bot.tree.sync()
        print(f"Synced {len(synced)} commands.")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception has occured while syncing tree:",e)

@bot.tree.context_menu()
async def translate(interaction: discord.Interaction, message: discord.Message):
    translated_text = str(message.content) + " :Translated." # Your translation code
    await interaction.response.send_message(translated_text,suppress_embeds=True,ephemeral=True)

bot.run(TOKEN)

Now you can right click a message and do Apps>translate.
